# Change font for ORACLE SQL but the display words are still small

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have tried `Tool-> preference -> search "font"` and make it bigger as this picture shown.

However, even I restart my ORACLE SQL, my font is till super small.

ps: I use windows10 and the version for ORACLE SQL Developer is 20.2

Anyone know how can I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried all the answers provided, but changing to system(enhanced) from high DPI scaling behavior has saved me.

**HOW:** 
Right Click on sqldeveloper application icon (.exe) and select Properties **>** Compatibility tab **>** Check the option of Override high DPI scaling behaviour **>** Select "**System ( Enhanced )**" in drop down below **>** click **Apply** **>** Re-Launch the application

Answer (score 1):

I also faced a similar issue when installed this on Windows 10. The issue has to do with compatibility settings. I have fixed it following the steps given below:

- Get shortcut of sqldeveloper at your desktop
- Ensure that you have admin rights in your PC
- Right Click on sqldeveloper icon and select Properties. Go to the Compatibility tab:

  - Compatibility mode change it to windows 7
  - Check the option of **Override high DPI scaling behaviour**
  - Select "System" in drop down below
  - Apply
- Re-Launch the application

Answer (score 1):

Please change the font size and test by typing in the SQL window. Below is the sniping

[image]

Comment: Thank you. However, as shown in my picture, I have tried to make my font size larger. And restart SQL. But it does not work.